# SQL User Defined Function Generates a Non-Boolean Type Error

Tags: sql, function, boolean, where-clause

I'm getting this error on a SQL user defined function:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected, near ')'.

For this:

```
UPDATE LMI_Contact
SET Phone = NULL
WHERE dbo.LMI_IsSingleCharacterRepeated(Phone, '0')
```

where the function can be created using:

```
-- ***this will also find NULL and empty string values***
CREATE FUNCTION LMI_IsSingleCharacterRepeated (@string varchar(max), @char char(1))
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index int
    DECLARE @len int
    DECLARE @currentChar char(1)
    SET @index = 1
    SET @len= LEN(@string)

    WHILE @index <= @len
    BEGIN
        SET @currentChar = SUBSTRING(@string, @index, 1)
        IF @currentChar = @char
            SET @index= @index+ 1
        ELSE
            RETURN 0
    END
    RETURN 1
END;
GO
```

This function is for checking if a string is any specified single character, repeated.

Comment: caution - my function will also find fields with null values or an empty string, so really needs a little more work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must use comparison operators against functions even if the return type is `bit`.

```
UPDATE LMI_Contact
SET Phone = NULL
WHERE dbo.LMI_IsSingleCharacterRepeated(Phone, '0') = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Try This

```
CREATE FUNCTION LMI_IsSingleCharacterRepeated (@str varchar(max), @char char(1))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @indx int
    DECLARE @len int
    DECLARE @currentChar char(1)
    SET @indx = 1
    SET @len= LEN(@str)

    WHILE @indx <= @len
    BEGIN
        SET @currentChar = SUBSTRING(@str, @indx, 1)
        IF @currentChar = @char
            SET @indx= @indx+ 1
        ELSE
            RETURN 0
    END
    RETURN 1
END;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this, but boolean isn't a recognised data type.  I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Updated again.. please check.

Comment: Good thinking and thanks again.  Use of reserved words in a query can easily catch a developer out.  In my case, this wasn't the problem.  I've upvoted the suggestion as useful :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify the where clause of your query as:

```
UPDATE LMI_Contact
SET Phone = NULL
WHERE dbo.LMI_IsSingleCharacterRepeated(Phone, '0') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil - just beaten to the answer by Thomas, so I've given you an upvote